# Setting Devise Login to be root page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, devise

I am using the following code for my routes:

```
devise_for :user, 
  :as => '', 
  :path_names => { 
    :sign_in => "", 
    :sign_out => "logout", 
    :sign_up => "register" 
  }
```

But when I'm logged out and I goto `/logout` I get the following error:

> No route matches {:action=>"new",
>   :controller=>"devise/sessions"}

How do I setup the root path to be to `:sign_in` action?

Answer (score 132, accepted):

To follow on from the people who are asking about the error `Could not find devise mapping for path "/"` there is a workaround.

You'll find that there is a clue in your logs which will probably say:

```
[Devise] Could not find devise mapping for path "/".
This may happen for two reasons:

1) You forgot to wrap your route inside the scope block. For example:

  devise_scope :user do
    match "/some/route" => "some_devise_controller"
  end

2) You are testing a Devise controller bypassing the router.
   If so, you can explicitly tell Devise which mapping to use:

   @request.env["devise.mapping"] = Devise.mappings[:user]
```

So I retried the approach but instead wrapping it (as @miccet suggets) inside a scope block:

```
devise_scope :user do
  root to: "devise/sessions#new"
end
```

This worked fine for me

Comment: This sent me off to an infinite loop, dear reader who has the same problem, the next step of the answer is here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19855866/how-to-set-devise-sign-in-page-as-root-page-in-rails

Answer (score 102):

```
devise_for :users

devise_scope :user do
  authenticated :user do
    root 'home#index', as: :authenticated_root
  end

  unauthenticated do
    root 'devise/sessions#new', as: :unauthenticated_root
  end
end
```

Just like this, tested on Rails Rails 4.1.0.rc1.

Comment: I suspect that it all depends on the version of Rails and Devise. This certainly works for Rails 4 with Devise 3 - most other answers didn't.

Comment: I think this is the best way to do it. It works with Rails 4.2.7.1 and Devise 4.2.0

Answer (score 23):

```
root :to => "devise/sessions#new"
```

I needed to set the default home root.  I felt like I had tried this all night last night (prior to posting the question), but it's working now.  If you're logged out, Devise attempts to redirect you to the root path which I had undefined.

Comment: ANY IDEA WHY I GET THIS?  Could not find devise mapping for path "/". Maybe you forgot to wrap your route inside the scope block?

Comment: There is a solution to this "could not find devise mapping" error which for the sake of clarity I've posted in a separate answer on this page: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12994856/400790

Answer (score 16):

<sub>*(This was posted as a [suggested edit](https://stackoverflow.com/suggested-edits/65703), but should have been an answer of its own. I don't know if it makes sense or not. Dear anonymous editor: feel free to repost this answer as your own, and leave me a comment so I'll delete this copy.)*</sub>

```
root :to => redirect("/users/login")
```

Comment: Please note, this route is a redirection. It does not display the sign in page on the root URL. To do this, you need to create the route 

    devise_scope :user do
      root :to => "devise/sessions#new"
    end

as suggested by @PeterNixey

Answer (score 12):

I got this to work with @VvDPzZ answer. But I had to modify it slightly

```
  devise_scope :business_owner do
    authenticated  do
      root to: 'pages#dashboard'
    end

    unauthenticated do
      root to: 'devise/sessions#new', as: 'unauthenticated_root'
    end
  end
```

I had to ad `to:` in the root path declaration. I also removed the `as: :authenticated_root` because I already had some places in my application referencing `root_path` in links. By leaving out the `as: :authenticated_root` part I didn't have to change any of my existing links.

Comment: Finally, after several hours. This is it: the answer I was looking for 

Answer (score 3):

I guess you have different user roles. If you do you have to add a scope like this to the users resource:

```
  devise_scope :user do
    get "/logout" => "devise/sessions#destroy"
  end
```

You can read more about overriding devise routes here:
[https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Change-the-default-sign_in-and-sign_out-routes](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To%3a-Change-the-default-sign_in-and-sign_out-routes)

Comment: It's not so much that I can't access the logout route.  It's when you're logged out the log out route redirects you to root.

Answer (score 1):

Some of these solutions are way too complex. Just use Rails:

Add `'get' 'users/root', to: 'users#root'` to config/routes.rb.

In UsersController do something like:

```
def root
  if user_signed_in?
    redirect_to root_for_signed_in_user_path (or whatever)
  else
    redirect_to new_user_session_path
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Using **rails 3.2** and **devise 3.2.3** I manage to setup my home page "**home#index**" (controller#action) as the login page making the following changes.

**#1** Added the login form to the home page:

```
<%= simple_form_for(resource, as: resource_name, url: session_path(resource_name)) do |f| %>
    <%= f.input :email %>
    <%= f.input :password %>
    <%= f.button :submit %>
<% end %>
```

**#2** Added methods resource_name, resource and devise_mapping to **app/heldpers/application_helper.rb**:

```
def resource_name
  :user
end

def resource
  @resource ||= User.new
end

def devise_mapping
  @devise_mapping ||= Devise.mappings[:user]
end
```

**#3** Created a custom sessions controller **app/controllers/users/sessions_controller.rb**:

```
class Users::SessionsController < Devise::SessionsController

   protected

   # This method tell sessions#create method to redirect to home#index when login fails.
   def auth_options
      { scope: resource_name, recall: 'home#index' }
   end

end
```

**#4** Skip the session routes and setup the custom sessions controller in **config/routes.rb**:

```
devise_for :users, path: 'auth', skip: [:sessions],
           controllers: {
               sessions: 'users/sessions'
           }

as :user do
  get 'auth/sign_in' => 'home#index', as: :new_user_session
  post 'auth/sign_in' => 'users/sessions#create', as: :user_session
  delete 'auth/sign_out' => 'users/sessions#destroy', as: :destroy_user_session
end
```

Answer (score -1):

I'm new on rails and I didn't know your 'device_scope' name have to be different to your 'device_for' name. Notice my example.

I tried this a hundred times a this is why it didn't work jajaja

```
  devise_for :user_devises, path: 'user_devises'

  devise_scope :user_devise do
    authenticated :user_devise do
      root 'home#index', as: :authenticated_root
    end
  
    unauthenticated do
      root 'devise/sessions#new', as: :unauthenticated_root
    end
  end
```