# set devise users/sign_up page as landing page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

I'm new to rails and I'm using devise to authenticate users.

I have a devise User model and I'm using devise views.

my routes.rb file goes like this

```
Freshconnection::Application.routes.draw do
 root to: 'pages#home'


 devise_for :admin_users, ActiveAdmin::Devise.config
 ActiveAdmin.routes(self)

 devise_for :users do
 ActiveAdmin.routes(self)
  get '/users/sign_out' => 'devise/sessions#destroy'
 end
```

As of now when I run the server, the request is routed to pages#home which is my landing page.

I want the users/sign_up page to be the landing page so that the user can sign_up and start using the website.

Please guide me on how this has to be accomplished.
Many thx

Answer (score 1):

As described here ([link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4954876/setting-devise-login-to-be-root-page)) you could try the workaround

```
devise_scope :user do
    root to: "devise/registrations#new"
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your `root` directive to:

```
root to: 'devise/registrations#new'
```

Comment: I tried that , but when I do , I get the following error......Unknown action

Could not find devise mapping for path "/". This may happen for two reasons: 1) You forgot to wrap your route inside the scope block. For example: devise_scope :user do get "/some/route" => "some_devise_controller" end 2) You are testing a Devise controller bypassing the router. If so, you can explicitly tell Devise which mapping to use: @request.env["devise.mapping"] = Devise.mappings[:user]