# How to set devise sign in page as root page in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, root

I have a devise Personality.

I would like to set the sign in page for the devise personality as the root page for my project.

What changes should I make in the `routes.rb`?

Rails version : 3.2.14

rake routes gives me the following for root

```
    root        /                                      devise/sessions#new
```

but still i get the welcome aboard rails page. (localhost:3000)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Add this to your routes.rb

```
devise_scope :user do
  root :to => 'devise/sessions#new'
end
```

but on doing this, after sign in you might get stuck in infinite loop error, so its better to add after sign in and after sign out path in your application controller by overriding the devise methods

```
def after_sign_in_path_for(resource_or_scope)
  # your_path
end

def after_sign_out_path_for(resource_or_scope)
  # your_path
end
```

This will work!

Comment: i have edited the answer, take a look

Comment: you have to remove index.html from public directory to delete welcome aboard page

Comment: I included the above code, still the root page is not changing.

Comment: it works, i deleted the index page from public folder and included the above code. thank you :)