# how to use new_user_session route from devise as the root path?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

Problem - I don't know how to set the `new_user_session` route from devise gem as the root path in Rails app.

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  devise_for :users
resources :dashboard
root to: "home#index"
```

Comment: Have you tried reading devise wiki and howtos?: https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-Tos

Comment: try `root to: 'sessions#new'`

Comment: not working uninitialized constant error!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Setting Devise Login to be root page](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4954876/setting-devise-login-to-be-root-page)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Place this line in routes.rb

```
devise_scope :user do
 root :to => 'devise/sessions#new'
end
```

You need to set default session route.

Answer (score 0):

Replace with .

```
devise_for :users, :controllers => {:registrations => "registrations", :sessions => "sessions"}
  devise_for :users do
    get '/users/sign_in', :to => 'devise/sessions#new', :as => :new_user_session
    get '/users/sign_out', :to => 'devise/sessions#destroy', :as => :destroy_user_session
  end
```

and root to

```
devise_scope :user do
  get "/" => "sessions#new"
end
```

---

Comment: It won't work. it should be `as :user do` on the second line.