# Direct user on sign-in in devise rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

How do I direct a user to a specific page after they have successfully signed in with devise?

I have installed devise and as they stipulate I have added `root to: 'home#index'`which I assume roots to the page where sign-in is rendered. What I can't figure out, is how I `redirect` a user to an already existing specific page like `'graph/data'` once they are signed in.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to redirect the user only once then you can overwrite the after_sign_in_path method wich is described in the devise documentation

[ref:](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-redirect-to-a-specific-page-on-successful-sign-in#)

```
## application_controller.rb
def after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
  sign_in_url = new_user_session_url
  if request.referer == sign_in_url
    super
  else
    stored_location_for(resource) || request.referer || root_path
  end
end
```

If you want that the user will redirect to a specific route if the user is  sign_in you can use devise_scope:

[ref:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4954876/setting-devise-login-to-be-root-page)

```
## routes.rb
devise_for :users
devise_scope :user do
  authenticated :user do
    root 'home#index', as: :authenticated_root
  end

  unauthenticated do
    root 'devise/sessions#new', as: :unauthenticated_root
  end
end
```

Answer (score 2):

In addition to the the bulleric's answer:

At second case:

```
## routes.rb
devise_for :users
devise_scope :user do
  authenticated :user do
    root 'graphs#data', as: :authenticated_root
  end

  unauthenticated do
    root 'home#index', as: :unauthenticated_root
  end
end
```

But for this case You could have 'GraphsController' with action 'data'.
Additionaly, You should use ':authenticate_user!' into this. For example:

```
  class GraphsController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :authenticate_user!
```