# Devise authenticate_user redirects to new session path

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

Devise `authenticate_user!` method redirects to new session path `Users::SessionsController#new`. Is there a way to configure this to redirect to the new user path?

```
Started GET "/" for ::1 at 2020-08-21 22:54:20 -0700
Processing by WelcomeController#index as HTML
Completed 401 Unauthorized in 2ms (ActiveRecord: 0.0ms | Allocations: 1174)


Started GET "/users/login" for ::1 at 2020-08-21 22:54:20 -0700
Processing by Users::SessionsController#new as HTML
```

Comment: https://github.com/heartcombo/devise/wiki/Redirect-to-new-registration-(sign-up)-path-if-unauthenticated - This might help you

Comment: Check this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/22070897/11883546

Answer (score 0):

When you press the login button by default it calls the create method of sessions controller to initiate the user's session.

#### sessions_controller.rb

```
 # POST /resource/sign_in

  def create
    self.resource = warden.authenticate!(auth_options)
    set_flash_message!(:notice, :signed_in)
    sign_in(resource_name, resource)
    yield resource if block_given?
    respond_with resource, location: after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
  end
```

The last line of this method is to call another method after_sign_in_path_for. By default, after_sign_in_path_for go to the root URL defined in the path of the route. You can override this method in the application controller.

#### application_controller.rb

```
def after_sign_in_path_for(user)
   stored_location_for(user) || new_user_url(user)
end
```